# Problems running code in OSX but not Windows

Tags: r, macos

I run the following code in R Studio for OSX and it halts, but not in RStudio for Windows. What gives?

When I run

```
mikebay_movies <- lapply(vrottenrate(mikebay_movies$Film), function(x) as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

it returns

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Full code

```
    #Create a function that will download movie info
rottenrate <- function(movie){
 require(RJSONIO)
  link <- paste("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=", movie, "&y=&plot=short&r=json&tomatoes=true", sep = "")
  jsonData <- fromJSON(link)
  return(jsonData)
}
vrottenrate <- Vectorize(rottenrate, "movie", SIMPLIFY = F)

#Puts in the data into a table
 mikebay_movies <- html("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bay") %>%
        html_nodes ('#mw-content-text > table:nth-child(42)') %>%
        html_table (fill = T) %>%
        as.data.frame

#Grab all of the info and put it into a dataframe
mikebay_movies <- lapply(vrottenrate(mikebay_movies$Film), function(x) as.data.frame(t(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
mikebay_movies_dt <- rbindlist(mikebay_movies,fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: There's an OMDB API package : https://github.com/hrbrmstr/omdbapi

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Latest R uses `setInternet2` by default if so. You may need to account for that on OS X. There's also an NA in the first row, not sure why that'd be problematic on only one OS though.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a better way to do it all 'round:

```
library(omdbapi)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(pbapply)

html("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bay") %>%
  html_nodes('#mw-content-text > table:nth-child(42)') %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE) %>% # *don't* use "T" (it kills kittens)
  extract2(1) %>%           # html_table returns a list; this is [[1]]
  filter(!is.na(Film)) %>%  # your scraper code has a data frame with NAs. remove them.
  rowwise() %>%             # apply the following "do" row-wise
  do(find_by_title(title=.$Film, type="movie", 
                   year_of_release=.$Year, 
                   include_tomatoes=TRUE)) -> mike_bay_movies

glimpse(mike_bay_movies)

## Observations: 12
## Variables:
## $ Title             (chr) "Bad Boys", "The Rock", "Armageddon", "Pearl Harbor", "Bad Boys II", "The ...
## $ Year              (chr) "1995", "1996", "1998", "2001", "2003", "2005", "2007", "2009", "2011", "2...
## $ Rated             (chr) "R", "R", "PG-13", "PG-13", "R", "PG-13", "PG-13", "PG-13", "PG-13", "R", ...
## $ Released          (date) 1995-04-07, 1996-06-07, 1998-07-01, 2001-05-25, 2003-07-18, 2005-07-22, 2...
## $ Runtime           (chr) "118 min", "136 min", "151 min", "183 min", "147 min", "136 min", "144 min...
## $ Genre             (chr) "Action, Comedy, Crime", "Action, Adventure, Thriller", "Action, Adventure...
## $ Director          (chr) "Michael Bay", "Michael Bay", "Michael Bay", "Michael Bay", "Michael Bay",...
## $ Writer            (chr) "George Gallo (story), Michael Barrie (screenplay), Jim Mulholland (screen...
## $ Actors            (chr) "Lisa Boyle, Will Smith, Martin Lawrence, Michael Taliferro", "Sean Conner...
## $ Plot              (chr) "Two hip detectives protect a murder witness while investigating a case of...
## $ Language          (chr) "English", "English", "English, Russian, Indonesian", "English, Japanese, ...
## $ Country           (chr) "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA...
## $ Awards            (chr) "1 win & 3 nominations.", "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 8 wins & 8 nomin...
## $ Poster            (chr) "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY4NDk1NTU5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjE...
## $ Metascore         (chr) "41", "59", "42", "44", "38", "50", "61", "35", "42", "45", "32", "N/A"
## $ imdbRating        (dbl) 6.8, 7.4, 6.6, 6.0, 6.5, 6.9, 7.1, 6.0, 6.3, 6.5, 5.8, 8.0
## $ imdbVotes         (dbl) 153208, 240659, 293093, 230508, 161893, 247077, 469215, 292303, 294781, 14...
## $ imdbID            (chr) "tt0112442", "tt0117500", "tt0120591", "tt0213149", "tt0172156", "tt039920...
## $ Type              (chr) "movie", "movie", "movie", "movie", "movie", "movie", "movie", "movie", "m...
## $ tomatoMeter       (int) 43, 66, 39, 25, 23, 40, NA, 19, 35, 49, 18, NA
## $ tomatoImage       (chr) "rotten", "fresh", "rotten", "rotten", "rotten", "rotten", "N/A", "rotten"...
## $ tomatoRating      (dbl) 4.9, 6.6, 5.2, 4.6, 4.1, 5.4, NA, 3.9, 4.9, 5.4, 3.9, NA
## $ tomatoReviews     (int) 47, 64, 115, 188, 176, 194, NA, 242, 246, 182, 180, NA
## $ tomatoFresh       (int) 20, 42, 45, 47, 40, 77, NA, 47, 87, 90, 32, NA
## $ tomatoRotten      (int) 27, 22, 70, 141, 136, 117, NA, 195, 159, 92, 148, NA
## $ tomatoConsensus   (chr) "Bad Boys stars Will Smith and Martin Lawrence have enjoyable chemistry; u...
## $ tomatoUserMeter   (dbl) 78, 86, 73, 67, 78, 64, 75, 58, 56, 47, 52, 85
## $ tomatoUserRating  (dbl) 3.5, 3.6, 3.5, 3.3, 3.6, 3.3, 3.9, 3.5, 3.5, 3.1, 3.3, 4.0
## $ tomatoUserReviews (int) 659318, 303907, 907616, 903898, 500480, 371029, 232, 4078681, 255142, 8424...
## $ DVD               (date) 2000-06-27, 1997-12-02, 1999-01-05, 2001-12-04, 2003-12-09, 2005-12-13, 2...
## $ BoxOffice         (chr) "N/A", "N/A", "$201.6M", "$197.8M", "$138.4M", "$35.8M", "N/A", "$402.1M",...
## $ Production        (chr) "Sony Pictures Home Entertainment", "Disney", "Buena Vista", "Touchstone",...
## $ Website           (chr) "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "http://studio.go.com/movies/pearlharbor/flash/index....
## $ Response          (chr) "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "T...
```